# Which template use in Netbeans 7.2 for index.php in a new project

Tags: php, netbeans, netbeans-7.2

When I create a new project PHP, file index.php is generated by default in the project.

If I change the new web page php template, next time I create a new project index.php doesn't reflect the change . But other new web page php are ok.

What is different for index.php.

Thanks in advance.